# Restructure an array with lodash by leveraging _.map and ._groupBy

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I am looking to restructure an array of objects with lodash.

I've been trying to adapt the many examples found online without any luck. It seems I would have to use a combination of `_.map` and `._groupBy` but I can't really wrap my head around this.

Any help is appreciated!

**Initial array**:

```js
const entries = [
  {
    year: '2019',
    children: [
      { name: 'red', amount: 1, label: 'color' },
      { name: 'yellow', amount: 20, label: 'color' },
      { name: 'green', amount: 12, label: 'color' },
    ],
  },
  {
    year: '2020',
    children: [
      { name: 'red', amount: 1, label: 'color' },
      { name: 'yellow', amount: 3, label: 'color' },
    ],
  },
]
```

**Restructured array**:

```js
[
  {
    id: 'red',
    data: [
      { year: '2019', amount: 1 },
      { year: '2020', amount: 1 },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 'yellow',
    data: [
      { year: '2019', amount: 20 },
      { year: '2020', amount: 3 },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 'green',
    data: [
      { year: '2019', amount: 12 },
    ],
  },
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could chain the whole operations with `flatMap`, `groupBy` and mapping.

```js
const entries = [{ year: '2019', children: [{ name: 'red', amount: 1, label: 'color' }, { name: 'yellow', amount: 20, label: 'color' }, { name: 'green', amount: 12, label: 'color' }] }, { year: '2020', children: [{ name: 'red', amount: 1, label: 'color' }, { name: 'yellow', amount: 3, label: 'color' }] }],
    result = _(entries)
        .flatMap(({ year, children }) => _.map(children, ({ name: id, amount }) => ({ year, id, amount })))
        .groupBy('id')
        .map((data, id) => ({ id, data: _.map(data, ({ year, amount }) => ({ year, amount })) }))
        .value();

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are probably quite a few different ways of doing this, however, I find the best approach is:

1. Flatten the children to one array.
2. Use _.groupBy to create a map of these entries keyed on name.
3. Use _.entries to get an array of keys and values for the map.
4. Finally use _.map to transform these entries into our desired output.

```js
const entries = [
  {
    year: '2019',
    children: [
      { name: 'red', amount: 1, label: 'color' },
      { name: 'yellow', amount: 20, label: 'color' },
      { name: 'green', amount: 12, label: 'color' },
    ],
  },
  {
    year: '2020',
    children: [
      { name: 'red', amount: 1, label: 'color' },
      { name: 'yellow', amount: 3, label: 'color' },
    ],
  },
]

// Step 1
let flattenedChildren = _.flatMap(entries, e => e.children.map(c => { return { ...c, year: e.year } }));

// Step 2
let entryMap =  _.groupBy(flattenedChildren , "name");

// Step 3
let mapEntries = _.entries(entryMap);

// Step 4
let result = _.map(mapEntries , ([id, items]) => { return { id, data: items.map(item => _.pick(item, ["amount", "year"]))} });

console.log("Result:", result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```